# (Python) How can I receive messages in real-time without refreshing?

Tags: python, server, udp, client

I have followed a tutorial from a YouTuber under the name of DrapsTV. This tutorial was made in Python 2.7 and makes a networked chat using UDP. I converted this to Python 3 and got everything to work. However, the way the threading is setup is that I have to send a message(or press enter, which is a blank message) to refresh and receive any messages from other clients. Here is the video incase you may need it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkfwX6RjRaI

And here is my server code:

```
from socket import *
import time


address = input("IP Address: ")
port = input("Port: ")


clients = []


serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serversock.bind((address, int(port)))
serversock.setblocking(0)


quitting = False
print("Server is up and running so far.")


while not quitting:
   try:
       data, addr = serversock.recvfrom(1024)
       if "Quit" in str(data):
           quitting = True
       if addr not in clients:
           clients.append(addr)
       print(time.ctime(time.time()) + str(addr) + ": :" + str(data.decode()))
       for client in clients:
           serversock.sendto(data, client)
   except:
       pass
serversock.close()
```

Here is my client code:

```
from socket import *
import threading
import time


tLock = threading.Lock()
shutdown = False


def receiving(name, sock):
   while not shutdown:
       try:
           tLock.acquire()
           while True:
               data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
               print(str(data.decode()))
       except:
           pass
       finally:
           tLock.release()


address = input("IP Address: ")
port = 0


server = address, 6090


clientsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
clientsock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
clientsock.bind((address, int(port)))
clientsock.setblocking(0)


rT = threading.Thread(target=receiving, args=("RecvThread", clientsock))
rT.start()


nick = input("How about we get you a nickname: ")
message = input(nick + "> ").encode()
while message != "q":
   if message != "":
       clientsock.sendto(nick.encode() + "> ".encode() + message, server)
   tLock.acquire()
   message = input(nick + "> ").encode()
   tLock.release()
   time.sleep(0.2)


shutdown = True
rT.join()
clientsock.close()
```

Comment: problem is nto socket or thread but `input()` which blocks all program. But there is no standard method for non-blocking `input()`. you can create two threads - one only for receiving from server and one for sending to server and `input()`.

Comment: @furas Would that solve it?

Answer (score 1):

@furas has kindly explained my issue for me: it is not my receiving methods that are flawed(such as my threading or functions), it is the input call that is preventing the client from not receiving anything. So, in order to fix this, I or anyone else having this issue needs to find a way to call for input when a certain button is pressed so that unless your typing, you can receive messages or data.

Thank you @furas! https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas